# Does a web server use a different port transport data?

Tags: apache-http-server, connection, port, webserver

Say I have a web server process listens to Port 80. When a client visits this site, will the server pick up a new port to establish connection for data transferring, or just use Port 80? Use default configuration of apache, lighttpd or nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any TCP connection is identified by tuple of 4 numbers:

```
source_ip, source_port, target_ip, target_port
```

It is only required that combination of all 4 numbers is unique. For web server in our example, `target_ip` would be public IP address of that server, and `target_port` would be `80` (or `443` for HTTPS).

To answer your question: server does NOT pick a new port when answering a connection - it is always listening on port `80`, but client does selection of port on a client side!

For example, suppose we have web server with public IP address `10.0.0.1`, and clients `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2` and `192.168.1.3` . If connection from client to server is still active, `netstat -4n` would print something like this:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address    State
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:80     192.168.1.1:65510  ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:80     192.168.1.2:49166  ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:80     192.168.1.3:49166  ESTABLISHED
```

As you can see, it is very much possible that 2 different clients could have exact same port number (`49166`) on their side - there is nothing wrong with that.

In other words, web server keeps talking over original TCP connection that client connected to (port `80`) until that conversation is finished and connection is closed. All response packets from web server are sent back using tuple `(source_ip, source_port)` as destination address, and `(target_ip, target_port)` as source address.

Comment: Thank you! But does this mean, at the instance when the server is responding to one client, another client's request will be ignore? Is  clients's system (browser, or OS, I don't know) implemented at TCP level, to retry several times to establish a connection?

Comment: No. Server listens for incoming connections on "listening" socket (created by `listen()` syscall). When connection is accepted, it will be promoted to active  connection (using `accept()` syscall). However, "listening" socket does not go anywhere and can still accept new connections.

Comment: Then one port can communicated simultaneously with many other ports? Sorry for my poor knowledge.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Like I said in the beginning, only 4-tuple `(source_ip, source_port, target_ip, target_port)` must be unique - this is all that is required to tell TCP connections apart. Other than that, there are no restrictions.